# aframe error during installation with npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, aframe

I'm trying to install aframe and aframe-inspector. 
I tried every way for local development because I need to to something that requires the editing of the inspector.
But every time I try to install it, it fails during npm install or npm start.
For example, when I try to install aframe, it gives me error in npm install.
For inspector during start.
I didn't find help since I seem the only one that has this kind of errors.
How can I solve? I just need to edit aframe-inspector and I don't know hot to do it without installing it and I don't know how to proceed even after but this seems the right way.
I tried in ubuntu and in windows 10.
Thx for future answers!

EDIT 1: I removed the part about the windows error. I don't need to make it work on windows, I don't want you to focus on that. I've got the last version of node.js.
Here you can see what kind of error I have when I try to install it.
 [Errors photos on drive](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ymI6FMAUS0HIKGFy49qyLtyJAKzHQknji7_Eiy-1SBs/edit?usp=sharing)

Here you can ses the log that I had when trying to install aframe with npm:  [Errors log while installing aframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bsAIXAVfMXcmYAz3djcaCj2HK0594sEO/view?usp=sharing)

EDIT 2: I tried the same things on 2 different PCs in ubuntu. I also tried **this**   [aframe boilerplate](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe-boilerplate/) . It didn't work either.

EDIT 3: I solved half of the problem. AFrame library now is working on local in my pc but the inspector isn't working. I solved the problem by updating node.js. I thought that was the last version because when I did **sudo apt-get install nodejs** my shell answered me that I had last version of node.js  but it wasn't true. Then I had a doubt about it and I found on internet that I had to install NVM and then I had to install node with it. So now I just need to make the inspector work. I couldn't find a way for now (the error of the inspector is still the same).

EDIT 4: I also tried in windows and it didn't work. I got 3 errors in 3 different situations:
- trying git clone [error with git clone](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JT8NA0s1za7DhrZDrQulObdInW8Z7sFs/view?usp=sharing) ;
Then, after npm install: 
- trying **npm start** without doing anything [error on npm start](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E2BTC22aY5S-q_UZNE5Njm-ZnUf-iwDd/view?usp=sharing)
- trying after **git init** in the inspector [after git init](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d5q6zYSe3GltlDUOeQhkyxWAzjerg1AM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please add the error stack to your question.

Comment: I've made the changes, let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using windows but I think to understand what was the problem.
First of all, I couldn't clone the project so I downloaded it directly from the site. I think that in that way it couldn't work.
I couldn't clone the project because I'm a beginner with the use of git I think. I think that there are some problems with public keys/SHA that I don't know how to solve. For this reason, in Windows, I downloaded Github Desktop and I made it handle for me. In that way, it worked. I don't have the direct solution for ubuntu but I think that this can help someone.

Comment: This worked for me.  Trying to clone the repo in VSCode failed on windows and downloading the repository made the `npm install` fail. Cloning with Github for Windows and then running `npm install` worked

Answer (score 1):

I got an older aframe version (current is 0.8.0) installed on Windows.
I could install it both on `node 6.9.0` and `node 8.10.0` (changing node version using nvm):

```
nvm use 8.10.0
npm cache verify
npm install aframe@0.7.0
```

Still I can't install current aframe@0.8.0, though.

---

I also did this change:

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

[(Link to a similar issue)](https://github.com/devsisters/DQN-tensorflow/issues/32#issuecomment-310317628) - while trying to get 0.8.0 installed.

---

Another option can be do download thee distribution from [here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/tree/master/dist) and place it in your solution

Hope this can be to some help.

Answer (score 0):

If you got an error about missing git, then you need to install git.

Check it out on the [website](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git). There are download links for windows, and terminal commands for ubuntu.

As far as i know git is necessary to fetch dependencies, so it should be a must have.

Comment: Thx for the answer, the problem of git in windows is that simply windows has not a command line that's similar to the unix/linux one, so installing it via npm lead to that error. But I'm trying to solve that problem in ubuntu. 
(in fact, that problem is not shown in ubuntu):
Thx for the answer!

Comment: @Pietro what about the windows shell ? cmd ? You can install git-scm and use it from the command line, just like npm

Comment: I tried like you said, since nothing works. And... It didn't work :/ I got 3 errors in 3 different situations:  
- trying git clone [error with git clone](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JT8NA0s1za7DhrZDrQulObdInW8Z7sFs/view?usp=sharing) ;
Then, after npm install: 
- trying **npm start** without doing anything [error on npm start](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E2BTC22aY5S-q_UZNE5Njm-ZnUf-iwDd/view?usp=sharing)  
- trying after **git init** in the inspector [after git init](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d5q6zYSe3GltlDUOeQhkyxWAzjerg1AM/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not plan to modify your local copy of A-Frame then directly using the minified version with `<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.0/aframe.min.js"></script>` should be enough.

You can also just [remix the existing Glitch](http://glitch.com/~aframe) in order to have a setup going live without setting up your own server.

On the other hand if you do want to modify A-Frame itself then yes you do need `git` to be installed and available in your path or using a GUI. Overall the toolchain relying on `git`, `npm`, etc is only necessary if you modify A-Frame and (arguably) provide value mostly if you are building a large project relying on those tools already.

Comment: Hi! Thx for your answer, like I said  before, I need to modify the inspector. So, I need to do it in local. And yes, the project is really big. 
The problem, like I wrote in the edit 4, was that git clone didn't work for some reason so I solved using GitHub Desktop to clone it. With GitHub Desktop it worked. Also, I didn't know that for having the last versione of nodejs the system requires nvm. But anyway, now My problem is solved.

Comment: The inspector is in another repository namely https://github.com/aframevr/aframe-inspector which includes an example of defining your own inspector in an existing A-Frame scene.

Comment: Maybe I'm not clear in the main topic, I'm sorry. I know that are 2 different repository and I needed both of them to work (aframe to understand how does aframe-inspector interacts with aframe) on my project. So, I had problem on both of them. I solved like I wrote above, btw. In ubuntu is still not working but I think is because of git in some way.